# What is an efficient way to log in AWS cloudwatch from your AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a set of 50 Lambda functions in AWS for a node project I am working on. Most of the functions are CRUD based. What is an efficient way to log variables and errors to Cloudwatch? By efficiency I mean with the least cost possible what should I log to Cloudwatch ? Currently I am logging my input, my query and errors. Is there a smart way to reduce costs by doing efficient logging? Please note that I am a young developer new to AWS. All feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to send logs from AWS Lambda to CloudWatch Logs, is using `console.log`. All logging will be send into one log group per lambda function without any further tooling.

I usually try to use some kind of JSON format in log files to allow later parsing (e.g. via metric filter)

```
log = { name: 'input', param1: 'input1', param2: 'input2' };
console.log(JSON.stringify(log));
```

This will produce the following output in CloudWatch Logs:

```
 2018-01-25T14:49:19.049Z   abdebade-01de-11ee-8afe-ff1c252182f2    {"name":"input","param1":"input1","param2":"input2"}
```

Comment: I decided to only use `console.error` and only log my errors. Logging queries and input were determined to be too cost intensive. Thanks for your reply though!